# Ambari HDP 2.2: Port 8020 Connection refused

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, ambari

So I have installed ambari over a cluster of three node AWS EC2 instances. All services show green, i.e., they all seem to be working fine. I can do all HDFS file operations. However, whenever I try to run a simple wordcount program on the instance, it says it cannot reach port 8020.

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/hdp/2.2.6.3-1/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.2.2.6.3-1.jar wordcount  /tmp/wordcount/in /tmp/wordcount/out
15/08/21 05:28:02 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://<fqdn for the namenode>:8188/ws/v1/timeline/
15/08/21 05:28:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at <fqdn for the namenode>/10.0.0.55:8050
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://<fqdn for the namenode>:8020/hdp/apps/2.2.6.3-1/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.getFileStatus(Hdfs.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.resolvePath(AbstractFileSystem.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$25.next(FileContext.java:2180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$25.next(FileContext.java:2176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolve(FileContext.java:2176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolvePath(FileContext.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.addMRFrameworkToDistributedCache(JobSubmitter.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The FQDN is the output of the command `hostname -f` which was used when creating the cluster.

I have tried telnetting too, but there too connection refused.

```
bt-prod-dev-02@ip-10-0-0-55:~$  telnet localhost 8020
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I am not sure where to look.

Comment: Can you verify that the port is listening on that host? What's the output of the following command? netstat -tupln | grep 8020

Comment: Hey @cjackson, yes the port was running. Actually the problem was too simple, I was just looking for an error which actually didn't exist. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple "FileNotFoundException", which I had expected ambari installation to take care. So the problem was solved once I put the file `/usr/hdp/2.2.6.3-1/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz` in `hdfs://<fqdn for the namenode>:8020/hdp/apps/2.2.6.3-1/mapreduce/`.